# C++ Formatting Using Iomanip

Tags: c++

I am trying to format the output of my code using iomanip:

```
cout.setf(ios::fixed);
cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
cout.precision(2) << "Modified: resistor "<< rname << " to "<< res << " Ohms"<<endl;
```

but i recieve an error on the third line:

```
error: invalid operands of types 'std::streamsize' and 'const char [20]' to binary 'operator<<'|
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << ... << '\n';
```

or:

```
std::cout.precision(2);
std::cout << ... << '\n';
```

The function `ios_base::precision` does not return the stream it operates on, so you can't stream anything into it directly.